# AWS s3 ls command returns error: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My account has two S3 buckets, both them have the same permission settings. The same account has one EB and an EC2 instance generated by the EB. There are several policies attached to this ec2 instance role, one policy is `AmazonS3FullAccess`.

I test accessing S3 buckets from that EC2 instance using command `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name`.
But received different results.
One bucket give the list of objects, but one bucket gives error: `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied`

Can you please give any comments on that?

[image]

Comment: Does the bucket that does not work have KMS encryption enabled? Or what's the bucket policy on it?

Comment: There is no bucket policy on both Buckets. If I add below bucket policy to the bucket that doesn't work, it does work. But I don't want to add bucket policy to it. I think KMS encrption is not enabled. can you tell how to check the KMS encryption? {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: In bucket properties you can check encryption status. If there are no bucket policies, what is the policy in your comment?

Comment: default encryption is disabled.

Comment: There is no bucket policy in the bucket permission settings. The policy I commented is just added for test.

Comment: Very strange indeed! If you run `aws s3 ls`, do both buckets appear in the listing? Do they both appear in your Amazon S3 console? (Just checking that they are in the same AWS account.)  Can we see the contents of the IAM Role attached to the EC2 instance? Does it work if you run the command from your own computer, with your own IAM credentials?